# Failed to start File System Check after crash? (Arch Linux)

Tags: linux, filesystems, crash, arch-linux, filesystem-corruption

Could this be a hardware problem?:

Recently my computer crashed. I was editing something in vim, next thing I know I can't save my changes because the filesystem is read-only. I was forced to reboot, and now on startup I get the following (have to manually copy because on tablet right now):

```
...
Mounted /boot
Reached target Login Prompts
Reached target Timers
Reached target Sockets
Started Emergency Shell
Reached target Emergency Shell

Failed to start File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/...
...
Dependency failed for /home
Dependency failed for Local File Systems
...
You are in emergency mode. After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to          view system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot,  "systemctl default" or ^D to boot into default mode.
Give root password for maintenance (or press Control-D to continue): _
```

This crash happened two times before this. I don't know what to do. Even if I knew what to do at this point, I don't know why the filesystem was going into read-only mode in the first place.

I'll provide any details I can. It might take me a while to provide more details, because I have to write them manually on a touch screen, but I will do it.

UPDATE: While I was writing this post, my computer was idling and now I get the following:

```
ata2: exdeption Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x4090000 action 0xe frozen
ata2: irq_stat ..., connection status changed
ata2: SError: { PHYRdyChg } 10B8B DevExch
```

I couldn't do anything, so I rebooted. I ran fsck as suggested:

```
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found. Fix <y>?
Inode ... was part of the orphaned inode list. FIXED.
Deleted inode ... has zero dtime. Fix<y>?
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
Block bitmap differences: ... Fix?<y>
Free blocks count wrong for group ... Fix<y>
... same stuff
Inode bitmap differences ... fix
Free inodes count wrong for group ... fix
... same stuff
/dev/sda4: FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED
... files (1.1% non-contiguous), ... blocks
```

It appears to boot now, but since it has crashed three times already, I'm wondering what's causing the problem and whether there's a bigger, underlying issue here.

Comment: Start by giving the root password, then `fsck -f /dev/disk/by-uuid/...` and post results.

Comment: @EugenRieck, I edited the post with the results. It appears to boot now, but I'm still not sure what caused the crashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 action needed to fix the problem:

- find and fix the root cause
- repair the file system

While the latter hast been achieved with `fsck -f /dev/disk/by-uuid/...`, the former is the more important.

Your log entries of

```
ata2: exdeption Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x4090000 action 0xe frozen
ata2: irq_stat ..., connection status changed
ata2: SError: { PHYRdyChg 10B8B DevExch
```

point to a hardware problem on a SATA bus. In my experience the first (and easiest and most likely to succeed) action to take is to reseat all SATA connections of the relevant Disk, even better to replace the SATA cable.